# can we use both java and flash in a single android application?

Tags: android, flash

We know that, with the help of Android NDK we can use .C files along with .java files in a single android application.

Similarly, is it possible to use Adobe Flash and Java files in a single android application ? If anybody know about this please reply me.

Thanks

Comment: if you have swf file then put it in webview.this is the way to migrate flash and android sdk

Comment: Can you suggest any site where i can get more information about this ??

Comment: you know about android webview?

Comment: thank you very much Dr.nik, I will try it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**yes.** you can use if you have swf file then put it in webview.this is the way to migrate flash and android sdk.put your swf file in assets and:::

```
String url ="file:///android_asset/hoge.swf";

WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);

wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Now if you planning to develop game in flash and generate apk so adobe air will help you. adobe have launch air to convert your game to apk file(which is compatible to android market).

just 2 to 3 step are there and you can generate apk easily .